# use SELECT and SESSION to check login user doesn't work

Tags: session, php

Could you tell me why this is not working? I just want to check whether the **userid** is really exists. if it does exist, means the registered users are able to do anything on the website. However, my coding doesnt work for that. One for registered users and another one for admin. My coding is something like this. Any idea?

```
session_start();

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM tablename
        WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION["userid"]."' ";
    $check = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1  && $_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') {
    echo "<p> HELLO </p> ";
            }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you start the Session on the top of the script?

Comment: @cyper open your eyes :) Can you do a var_dump of the variables sessions just after session_start() please?

Comment: @zeflex could you give an example please? like i dont know how to start..

Comment: @zeflex i see only an extract, not the hole script. See the doc on php.net:
    Note:

    To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: @user3246061 your if-conditions says: your session-username ist set, the username is in the database and the username ist 'admin'. is this correkt? or do you want to ask "is the username in the database OR is the username "admin")

Comment: @user3246061 do a search about var_dump on google... Cyper, he have the session_start() on top...

Comment: @cyper hey, no mate, my IF condition says the username is in the database and username is admin. I want both.. Without username, the user can't read **HELLO**. So what can I do?

Comment: @zeflex I know about var_dump, but just that is not working..

Comment: @cyper I've always put `session_start()` on the top of the page.

Comment: @user3246061 session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); die; and paste here the result.

Comment: **string(10) "freelancer" ["message"]=> string(0) "" }**. Finally, what is this result?

Comment: so confusing... is this a login script? if the `$_SESSION['userId']` already exists, you should not need to check the DB. you don't need to confirm the user exists in the DB every HTTP request. that's the point of the $_SESSION vars

Comment: @AndrewBrown this is not login script. Okay, let me try to be clear again, the login is really success anyway, and im going to make in another page, something like, if userid is exist, that user can find the button on a webpage, but if the userid is not exist, then the user couldn't get the button on a webpage. So, I don't need to check DB right? can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517398/session-is-not-working-to-check-login? Is it something like this? I tried that and it's not working as well.

Comment: if you have already logged in your user (checked against DB, and set $_SESSION vars), the you can simply use the conditional `if(isset($_SESSION['userId']))` wherever you need to only display something to valid users. no need to check the DB again

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't work at all. Stressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faked it and it worked for me. Make sure there is a value in session and if your database connection is ok. The mysqli_error will show possible failures (always thrown errors in your code).

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION["userid"]."' ";
$check = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

if (mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1  && $_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') {
    echo "<p> HELLO </p> ";
}
```

Comment: Is that really works for you? How come mine is not working? so weird? Is that okay if that `userid` is a number?

Comment: The session can be created at any point in the script in your project. Not necessarily need to have this session created and assigned this code. In my case I faked creating it at runtime. I made it clear from the beginning of the response that you need to check if the session is being created.

Answer (score -1):

```
    session_start();
$sel="select * from register where userid='$userid' and password='$pass'";
$res=  mysql_query($sel);
$co=  mysql_num_rows($res);
echo $co;             

if($co>0) {
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);  
$_SESSION['id']=$row['userid'];   
header("echo 'helloooooooo'");
} else {
echo "Invalid userid....";
}
header("location:login.php");
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, however this is not the one I want. what i want is to check whether the user logged in and it will appear **HELLO**.

Comment: and if possible, use mysqli, because mysql is so looongggg deprecated.